# IDE update changed font, how I can reset the font back?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-font

I just updated PyCharm this month, April 2020, and after updating the font changed to this strange font. In Editor -> Font -> Font I have it set to Jetbrains Mono, this isn't Jetbrains mono though. I tried switching to a few other fonts, but it seems to be stuck on this one. Any idea how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Default fonts used before 2020.1 version depending on the OS:

```java
public final static String FALLBACK_FONT_FAMILY         = "Monospaced";
public final static String MAC_OS_DEFAULT_FONT_FAMILY   = "Menlo";
public final static String LINUX_DEFAULT_FONT_FAMILY    = "DejaVu Sans Mono";
public final static String WINDOWS_DEFAULT_FONT_FAMILY  = "Consolas";
```

You can change the font at File | Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Font.

[image: original fonts]

Comment: I have gone to Editor -> Font and set the font to JetBrains Mono, just like your screenshot shows. I'm still getting this goofy font, not JetBrains mono, even after a restart.

Comment: Please share the logs: Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data. [Upload the file here](https://uploads.services.jetbrains.com/) and specify the name in the comment so that we can find it. I would recommend reporting such issues at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA or contact support directly via https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new.

Comment: See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085 for more details how to find the logs.

Comment: Found them, I uploaded the file, superdee_font_issues.log. I also have Webstorm installed, and the JetBrains mono font works just fine on Webstorm, so I don't think it's an issue with the font not being installed.

Comment: Does the issue persist if you run the IDE with the default settings? File | Manage Settings | Restore Default Settings?

Comment: Restoring default settings did not fix the issue.

Comment: Even uninstalling and reinstalling didn't fix this issue. Maybe 2020.1 has a bug and this is the only font that shows? Can I revert to a previous version?

Answer (score 0):

The update changed my font-size to 13 px instead of 12 px, which made it look significantly different.

Comment: It may help if you install the latest font version from https://github.com/JetBrains/JetBrainsMono/releases . Vertical height/rendering is different in the new versions. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-2264 could be also the case, see if removing the custom antialiasing options helps.