# IntelliJ 2020 Update changes font

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2020

IntelliJ just prompted me to update to the latest version which is 2020.1 for Community. When I completed that, my fonts changed. Does anyone know what they should be?

Very frustrating to have user settings changed like that.

Comment: I hope that there are no other settings with changes that are hidden to me for now.

Comment: This question already has the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61396259/104891.

Answer (score 1):

After making my question, someone else at work told me what their settings were that hadn't updated. In case you also have this problem, it's Consolas by default for me. Size 13, Line spacing 1.2.

[image: Font screenshot]

Comment: This question already has the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61396259/104891.

Comment: that's helpful. That question didn't have an intellij tag so I couldn't find it when searching.

Comment: It [did have the proper tag](https://i.imgur.com/UL6XUBd.png).

Comment: No, it didn't. I searched for intellij-idea-2020. I just added that tag to the other question, so NOW it does (when approved) but it didn't then. If I was searching in just the regular intellij-idea tag, there are 30,000 questions tagged with that. Adding the 2020 had only 2 initially.

Comment: Version specific tags should not be used: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85744/158528.

Comment: "I would only use version tags when the question content is irrevocably tied to a specific version of something and can never be relevant to earlier versions or later versions." I would say this this is specific to 2020 only. I've never had an issue with any other version.

Comment: Why do you think it can't be relevant for the later versions? Most users will not use version tags to search anyway.

Comment: Anything can be possible, which would imply that then there should never be a version tag created period. Thankfully this is one small setting change, but I would hope this would never happen again as changing settings like this is bad for user experience and would hopefully be added to some series of regression tests on upgrades.

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-231538#focus=streamItem-27-4083389.0-0.